# Index out of range when printing adjacent letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, indexoutofrangeexception

I have string which is as follows below

```
stg = 'AVBFGHJ'
```

I want the adjacent letter to be printed as expected below

```
AV

VB

BF

FG

GH

HJ

J None
```

I tried below code but throws me error like Index out of Range

**My code :**

```
for i in range(len(stg)):
    print(stg[i],stg[i+1])
```

Comment: Yes, when `i` reaches the end of `len(stg)`, then what happens if you call `i+1`?

Comment: @GAVD : Any trick to solve

Comment: what about iterating NOT upt o the last letter? Or checkin if the letter is last then not adressing to the post-last letter? or something else?

Comment: To clarify... What would the output be if sig = 'AVBFGHJK'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is meant to happen. You are accessing an index that is out of the range of the string.

If you really want to do it this way however, you can do something like this

```
stg = 'AVBFGHJ'
for i in range(len(stg)):
    if (i + 1) < len(stg):
        print(stg[i],stg[i+1])
    else:
        print(stg[i], None)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy pythonic approach is to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

stg = 'AVBFGHJ'

for x in zip_longest(stg, stg[1:]):
    print(*x)
```

With python ≥3.10, you can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
print(*(f"{a}{b}" for a,b in itertools.pairwise(stg)), sep='\n')
```

*Thanks [@chrslg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74427904/index-out-of-range-when-printing-adjacent-letter/74428196#comment131438356_74428196) for the remark.*

Without `itertoools`, you can handle the last case separately:

```
for x in zip(stg, stg[1:]):
    print(*x)
print(stg[-1], None)
```

Output:

```
A V
V B
B F
F G
G H
H J
J None
```

Comment: What this stg[1:] does.. Please explain

Comment: @nogoriv567 it slices the string to remove the first character

Comment: Why not just `itertools.pairwise` if you use `itertools`?

Comment: @chrslg you could but as it's a quite recent addition to `itertools` it's not yet available on all platforms

Comment: Yeah, but that a quite useful one :D `print(*(f"{a}{b}" for a,b in itertools.pairwise(stg)), sep='\n')`

Comment: I added it for completeness